# ajaxtoolkit calender extender won't show all the dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit

im trying to make textbox which will handle different dates. For that im using ajaxtoolkit so that when a user clicks on the textbox a popup calender will appear beneath the textbox. I have managed to do that but the problem is that it only shows arond 18 days of the month and i would like to show all of the days in a month. I'm attaching a picture so you can see how it looks. 
[image: calender extender]

Here is the code:

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtValidFrom" runat="server"TextMode="DateTime" >
</asp:TextBox></td>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtValidFrom" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" >
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems your CSS rules conflict with [Calendar CSS rules](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/Styles/Calendar.css).

You can strip all custom CSS to see that Calendar renders correctly and determine what code actually affects Calendar's CSS.

Comment: I only have on custom CSS class and i have not made any calender code in it. How should i move forward?

Comment: You can open Calendar page at [Sample site](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx), inspect its CSS in browser's debugger (F12, right-click on Calendar -> Inspect element) and compare it with your Calendar CSS.